# Storing constants in value objects

Tags: java, oop, javabeans

I have a VO object of the following form in addition

```
public class DummyVO {
    private int id;
    private String message;
    //getters and setters.

    //set of constants that describe the DummyVO. 
    public static final String MESSAGE_CONST1 = "A-> Const value for message";
    public static final String MESSAGE_CONST2 = "B-> Const value for message";
}
```

I was wondering whether the above is good practice or whether it makes sense to move the constants into a separate class. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is there a closevote? is there more information needed? Please comment if so.

Comment: It is voted to be closed because it is primarily opinion based. You ask 100's of developers, you're going to get a lot of difference answers :-)

Comment: thanks for commenting.. Is there no set standard or OOP guideline on this?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - Check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive answer except you can say

- the JDK has constants in interface and classes.
- creating an interface or class just to hold constants is generally avoided IMHO.

> Is there no set standard or OOP guideline on this?

None AFAIK.  The guideline should be to layout your classes in a manner you believe makes sense.

> public class TestVO{

Test value objects are usually placed in your test area.  It is worth noting that

- test code doesn't have to be as best practice as production code.  Sometimes doing unexpected things makes a good test.
- data driven tests are usually structured differently to regular code. i.e. I suspect you don't need to define these constant at all, just use them in your test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TestVO was a bad name . I should have gone with `DummyVO`. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering whether the above is good practice or whether it makes
>   sense to move the constants into a separate class

It depends on whether the constants *make sense* to stay close to the class.

For example, the following **could be argued** to make sense:

```
public class Product{
   private int id;
   private String category = DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CATEGORY;

   // setters and getters, constructors and what not

  public static final String DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "Uncategorized";
}
```

In this hypothetical example, the constant (`DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CATEGORY`) is tightly related to the category field in the Product class. So it might make sense to have that constant in that class. It could also be argued that we need a Category class (or enumeration) that contains that constant.

On the other hand, this would not make sense:

```
public class Product{
   private int id;

   // setters and getters, constructors and what not

  public static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "some error";
  public static final float PI_APPROXIMATION = 3.14159;
}
```

In this (albeit exaggerated) example, one constant (ERROR_MESSAGE) is too generic, it is not specific to what the Product class might represent. The second constant (PI_APPROXIMATION) is even worse as there really no reason to have such a thing.

So, there are no guidelines other than those that answer the following question: **Does it make sense to put that there?**

Constants are meant to represent something *for somebody* or *something*. So those constants need to be grouped close to those things that uses them, in a manner that makes sense. Classes and interfaces are not just open boxes that we throw things at them.

The fundamental challenge in software engineering is in designing things that make sense. And what makes sense is specific to the problem and situation at hand.